Using "screencapture" sometimes only takes screenshot of wallpaper
I have a working Python script that take screenshots of my single macOS display every minute using screencapture. The script essentially loops
os.system(f'screencapture {output}.png').
Every once in a while, the screenshots suddenly start only showing my wallpaper. I know this isn't a screen recording permissions issue for Python, since the script works 99% of the time. Furthermore, once the buggy behavior starts, taking screenshots with screencapture myself on Terminal.app does the same thing. The bug never goes away by itself.
The only fix I've found so far is to frustratingly restart my computer. Is there any documentation or fix for this behavior?
Edit: To clarify, I am still able to take non-glitched screenshots with keyboard shortcuts like Shift + Command + 3.

What are you capturing? A specific app? Depending on what player you use you can't screeencap video files with DRM. But those (I think) just show a blank black frame not the desktop

Does it occur when you use the key-press screen capture commands ?

@IconDaemon Ah, thanks for asking. I can still take screenshots with key-press screen capture commands like shift+command+3.

@SteveChambers I'm taking screenshots of my entire screen and all the windows visible.

What is the script you are using exactly?

Do you see the glitch when you use key-press screen captures, or only when the script is run? Also: when you run the script manually, has it ever glitched?

@IconDaemon The glitch never happens with key-press screencaptures. I realized that resetting the screen recording permissions for Terminal fixes the issue. Hopefully adding /usr/sbin/screencapture and the path to my script to the Screen recording permissions settings page prevents this from happening from now on.

Answer from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61051568/27245331
Your Terminal app probably doesn't have access to screen. Change in System Settings app (or whatever it is called, my Mac is not english) in "Screen capture and sound recording" (this too may be called differently).

If your screencapture command occasionally captures only your wallpaper instead of the active display content, it suggests a macOS graphics or display rendering issue rather than a script-specific problem.
Try to check system load and resources using Activity Monitor, ensure macOS is up to date, and consider resetting PRAM/NVRAM. Updating display-related software and checking Console logs for relevant errors could also provide insights.
Look in the Console app (under Applications > Utilities) for any error messages or warnings related to graphics or screencapture around the time the issue occurs.
